# Converting 2005 to 2008, System.Core project issues

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2005

Hey all! I converted my 2.0 site to 3.5 so I can take advantage of using LINQ. It converted the solution to 2008 okay, but the only project/site I can use LINQ in is the UI [web site]. All the sub projects (Business, Data, Model, Utility) can't add a reference to System.Core. It's greyed out. So, I can't add the namespace System.Linq to take advantage of the features.

The only layer that works is my UI layer. The solution loads and compiles fine in VS2K8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Annnnd, I found out why. For the website, you set the Target Framework, however for Projects, you have to change the following:

Right click Properties on project
Click Compile tab
Click on Advanced
Change framework from 2.0 to 3.5

Works like a charm now. I thought my solution converted over fine, but I guess not!

Comment: I had the same problem!  It was driving me batty! THANKS!